# Nock - Get matched hostname

Tags: nock

I want to mock an internal host naming scheme, like this.

```
nock(/some-internal.(ds1|ds2|ds3).hostname/)
  .get("/info")
  .reply(200, (???, requestBody) => {
    if(??? === "d1") {
      // return mock for d1
    } else if (??? === "d2") {
      // return mock for d2
    }
    // ... 
})
```

The first parameter of the callback is the path without the base url, so is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `ClientRequest` instance from inside the callback using the context.
[Docs for accessing the original request and headers.](https://github.com/nock/nock#access-original-request-and-headers)

```
const scope = nock(/some-internal.(ds1|ds2|ds3).hostname/)
  .get('/info')
  .reply(function (uri, requestBody) {
    console.log('host:', this.req.options.host)
    // ...
  })
```

Comment: thx for your reply. it worked for me with `this.req.options.host`

I will accept your answer after you updated your reply :)